How to programatically get size of the EEPROM where the bios is stored
I tried getting Bios Rom size from Dmidecode which says 16MB. But the vender specs says it should be 32MB. Is there any way to dive in and read the size of the whole chip (ROM where bios is stored). For reference check the picture attached.

That's a Winbond 25Q256JVFQ, which is one variant of the 25Q256JV, a 256 Mbit (= 32 MiB) SPI flash chip. The "FQ" suffix indicates the package type (F = 16-pin SOIC 300-mil) and options (Q = QE register fixed to 1 to make the chip backward compatible with the FV chip family).
The datasheet is publicly available, and pages 64-69 describe the SPI bus instructions that can be used to programmatically identify the chip using its JEDEC ID and/or Serial Flash Discoverable Parameters (SFDP for short). The latter includes the size of the chip.
Since year 2017, the spi-nor MTD driver of Linux apparently already can read and parse the SFDP of this chip model and several others.
First, you'll need to load a SPI master driver for your hardware. On this computer (Intel Z390 chipset) the SPI controller is visible on the PCI bus: (lspci -nn listing)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller [8086:a324] (rev 10)

The spi_intel_pci driver (in standard kernel source code) supports this device, so it is automatically loaded at boot as soon as the PCI bus is probed by the kernel, if it's included in the kernel configuration.
It will then auto-probe the SPI bus, find the flash chip and load the spi-nor kernel module, producing messages like this in dmesg:
[  +0,002085] spi-nor spi0.0: w25q128 (16384 Kbytes)
[  +0,000797] Creating 1 MTD partitions on "0000:00:1f.5":
[  +0,000002] 0x000000000000-0x000001000000 : "BIOS"

Those messages already indicate the spi-nor driver has already identified the type and size of the flash chip. But you can also use the lsmtd command as root, and get output like this:
DEVICE MAJ:MIN NAME TYPE SIZE 
mtd0    90:0   BIOS nor   16M

Also, in /sys/class/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0/spi-nor/ directory, the flash chip's JEDEC ID, manufacturer name, chip model and the contents of the SFDP are directly available as virtual files. /sys/class/mtd/mtd0/size provides the size of the chip as a simple number of bytes.
To use the spi-nor driver, you'll first have to have a driver for the SPI bus on your system.
If there is no such driver for your hardware yet, you would have to find the programming datasheet for your system chipset and figure out if it allows SPI bus access while the OS is running, and how to use it if possible. Then you would have to write a driver for your SPI bus.

can I get a more detailed process of using the spi-nor MTD Driver to get the size of this chip module ?
